# How does MySQL server find the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to what algorithm does MySQL server use to find the table. I mean when we do `select * from user`. How does it get to user table.

Just want to know if the number of tables and performance are inversely proportional or just that we don't have to care about it when designing db for an application

Answer (score 2):

MySQL 5.x uses the filesystem. A schema is a directory under the datadir. A table metadata is stored in a file in the directory like `user.FRM`. The corresponding datafile is also named for the table, so it's in a file `user.ibd` in the same directory.

So finding a table is as fast as opening a file by pathname.

If you have hundreds of thousands of files in one directory, that could result in some overhead to find the file. But it only has to do that once, as it first opens the table. For all subsequent queries, it keeps a filehandle open while it is using the table.

It's likely that the cost of executing an SQL query, reading rows, and formatting the result set is far more expensive than opening the table.

Answer (score 1):

If the hardware resources are high (especially RAM, number of tables / databases does not matter on performance.

But...

Design in the best way. Never think of easy designing.

Keey each entity as a row in any one table only (only exception being the key fields which will be used in other tables too). This way, you will arrive at a best design and there will no duplication hence no wastage of resources.

Master to have

```
name char(50),
place char(20),
mobile char(10)
id int unique key auto_increment
```

and transaction files to have

```
bill ...
billdate ...
qty ...
rate ...
personid int
```

and never to store the same person name in transaction. Once this is done, you will not (just like that) add tables.

Think the server as a costlier resource and think of each and every request you are going to send to the server (all the coming days) as wastage of your pocket money.